# Unable to startproject due to settings.py not found

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Executing the following command

`(env_mysite) C:\Users\acer>django-admin startproject mysite`

produces the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "d:\ash\software\python3\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> File "d:\ash\software\python3\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\acer\env_mysite\Scripts\django-admin.exe__main__.py", line
>   9, in
>
> File
>   "c:\users\acer\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 367, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
>
> File
>   "c:\users\acer\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 316, in execute
>       settings.INSTALLED_APPS
>
> File
>   "c:\users\acer\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 53, in __getattr__self._setup(name)
>
> File
>   "c:\users\acer\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 41, in _setup self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> File
>   "c:\users\acer\env_mysite\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 97, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>
> File "c:\users\acer\env_mysite\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> File "", line 978, in _gcd_import
>
> File "", line 961, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 936, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 205, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed
>
> File "", line 978, in _gcd_import
>
> File "", line 961, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 948, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'C:\Users\acer\mysite\mysite\settings'

Comment: You are using windows, right?

Comment: Yes,Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Open console and type `setx`. Do you get an error?

Comment: Did my solution worked for your case?

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `setx`, open a terminal and do this:

```
setx DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ""
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Let me know if that worked.